# Why does this keyRef not work with the xml

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to refer to a xsd key with a refkey but I am getting an error I cant make anything off.

When comparing against an xml [on here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.Xo8ORcgza73) I get this message for all lines where I use a `t` element

`Error - Line 14, 36: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 36; Identity Constraint error:  identity constraint "KeyRef@267613e6" has a keyref which refers to a key or unique that is out of scope.` 
(They @NUMBER) changes to random other numbers whenever I re check he whole thing. Also both documents are well formed and valid on their own.

I thought that I might have made some mistake with the key, but wouldn't that be an error with the key then?
Also with in the keyref I want to target the `t` element. I tried `self` and `.` which one should I use?

This is the keyref I have its placed in `art/artistsTagType/t`.
Where art is the root element and artistsTagType is a complexType containing the t element. (Its used more than once)

```
            <xsd:keyref name="tagRef" refer="tagKey">
                <xsd:selector xpath="?"/>
                <xsd:field xpath="?"/>
            </xsd:keyref>
```

The tagKey I try to reference is in `art/objects/object/tags` where all of them are elements.

```
            <xsd:key name="objKey">          
                <xsd:selector xpath="art/objects/object"/>
                <xsd:field xpath="@title"/>
                <xsd:field xpath="@catalog"/>
            </xsd:key>
```

My problem is probably very trivial but I am new to xsd and xml and cant make anything of it, any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the (shortend) xsd document I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="art">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="artists">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xsd:element name="artist">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="lived">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:attribute name="from" type="xsd:date" use="required"/>
                                                <xsd:attribute name="to" type="xsd:date"/>
                                                <xsd:attribute name="birthplace" type="xsd:string"/>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="tags" type="artistTagsType"/><!-- Use one -->
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:attribute name="aid" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:key name="artistKey">
                                    <xsd:selector xpath="art/artists/artist"/>
                                    <xsd:field xpath="@aid"/>
                                </xsd:key>
                                <xsd:keyref name="artistRef" refer="artistKey">
                                    <xsd:selector xpath="art/objects/object/label/year/ref"/>
                                    <xsd:field xpath="@aid"/>
                                </xsd:keyref>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="objects">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="object" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded"> <!--maxOccures default is 1-->
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:all>
                                        <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="catalog">
                                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                    <xsd:pattern value="([A-Z]{2})-([0-9]{3})-([a-z][0-4])"/>
                                                </xsd:restriction>
                                            </xsd:simpleType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="tags" type="artistTagsType" minOccurs="0" /><!-- Use two-->
                                    </xsd:all>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:key name="objKey">                 
                        <xsd:selector xpath="art/objects/object"/>
                        <xsd:field xpath="@title"/>
                        <xsd:field xpath="@catalog"/>
                    </xsd:key>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="tags">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="tag" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                                        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:attribute name="tagname" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        </xsd:extension>
                                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:key name="tagKey">         <!-- The key-->
                        <xsd:selector xpath="parent/tag"/>
                        <xsd:field xpath="@tagname"/>
                    </xsd:key>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="artistTagsType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="t" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="3" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:unique name="artistTagsTUnique">
                    <xsd:selector xpath="."/>  <!-- Element in t lists should be unique locally -->
                    <xsd:field xpath="."/>
                </xsd:unique>
                <xsd:keyref name="tagRef" refer="tagKey"><!-- Key Ref-->
                    <xsd:selector xpath="."/>
                    <xsd:field xpath="."/>
                </xsd:keyref>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The key belongs to the tags element in the schema it, in the objects and artists elements I am using the t elements that refer to it.

EDIT 2:
So the unique constraint is supposed to be local.

```
   <tags>
     <t>David</t>
     <t>The Pity</t>
   </tags>
   ....
   <tags>
      <t>Alaskan Waterfall</t>
      <t>David</t>
   </tags>
```

This should be possible while

```
<tags>
 <t>David</t>
 <t>David</t>
</tags>
```

should be forbidden.
And since I use the `t` type within different `tags` elements I wanted to declare the uniqueness within the `t`. (One is withing the object element and one is in the artist element

For the key:
The document should contain a list of tags that use the `tagKey`. Now artists and objects both have a `tags` element (optional for objects) containing a number of `t` elements. Where the content of said `t` elements should reference the `tagKey`.

Answer (score 0):

The rules when `xs:key` and `xs:keyRef` have different scope (that is, when they are defined on different elements) are extremely complicated -- although I've implemented the spec, I still have great difficulty with them. And I've seen very few cases where this is actually necessary.

I can't tell you what you've done wrong without seeing the full detail of what you've actually done; and I can't tell you how to fix it without seeing what constraint you are actually trying to impose. But in nearly all cases, xs:key and the corresponding xs:keyref should be defined in the same element declaration.

Specifically, if the rule is of the form "within an A, every value of X must refer to a value of Y that exists exactly once within A", then the key and keyref should both be defined in the element declaration for A.

**UPDATE**

An update, now that you've shown us your schema.

First, the `<xs:unique>` constraint is clearly wrong. When you write

```
<xsd:element name="t" type="xsd:string">
  <xsd:unique name="artistTagsTUnique">
                 <xsd:selector xpath="."/>  <!-- Element in t lists should be unique locally -->
                 <xsd:field xpath="."/>
             </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

You're actually saying "Within a t, every . must have a unique value for .". But t is a string, it doesn't have multiple contained elements that need to be unique within an instance of `t`. I suspect you want t to be unique within `tags`, in which case the constraint applies to element `tags`, and it should be

```
<xsd:element name="tags" type="xsd:string">
  ...
  <xsd:unique name="artistTagsTUnique">
      <xsd:selector xpath="t"/>  
      <xsd:field xpath="."/>
  </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

Now with `tagKey/tagRef` I'm having more trouble working out what you're trying to achieve (reverse engineering the requirements from incorrect code has never been my strong point). You've used the selector `parent/tag`, but I don't see an element named `parent` anywhere. Perhaps you wanted `parent::tag`, but of course you're not allowed an upwards selection like that. It seems you're trying to say that the value of the `t` element must be a tag (keyword) that's defined somewhere else in the document, but I'm having trouble seeing where that "somewhere else" is.

Comment: I just added a code snipped showing the document.
So the key marks the tags that are than to be used within the t elements. but the t elements are not in the same element as the key.

Comment: Thanks i added clarification about my goals to the post.
Yes I wanted to use ```parent::tag``` I thought this might be possible since the parent element is named ```tags``` in both cases.

The somewhere else of the ```t``` element is in the ```tag``` element that is within the ```tags``` element in the root of the document.